# find_by_id returning nil class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, controller, null

hi i am attempting to do a find_by_id, though when calling this method if the id doesnt exist im getting nil class

```
if current_user.admin?
  @schedules = Schedule.all
elsif current_user.team_id?
  @schedules = Schedule.find_by_team_id(current_user[:team_id])
end
```

error

NoMethodError in Schedules#index

Showing /Users/***/Sites/Rails/****/app/views/schedules/index.html.haml where line #44 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #44):

```
41:               %th Location
42:               %th{:style => "color: #675100;background: url(\"/img/sprites/alertboxes/bg-warning.png\") repeat-x #ffe68b;"} Manager
43:           %tbody
44:             - @schedules.each do |schedule|
45:               %tr
46:                 %td= event_display(schedule.event)
47:                 %td
```

Comment: This is the normal behaviour if you are using find_by_<attr_name> will return nil if no record is found for that attribute. Also note that find_by_<attr_name> returns only a record not an Enumerable. you should you where(...) or find_all_by_<attr_name> instead.

Comment: What do you expect it to do instead?

Comment: thnaks vvlad that find_all_by has fixed the issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behaviour if you are using find_by_ will return nil if no record is found for that attribute. Also note that find_by_ returns only a record not an Enumerable. you should you where(...) or find_all_by_ instead

Answer (score 0):

The difference between finding an object by id and finding an object by attribute are:

1. **Primary Key Finder Method** (by ID)

   `@schedules = Schedule.find(<schedule_id>)`

   **Result**: Returns an object if found. Throws an error if not found.
2. **Dynamic Finder Method** (by any Attribute)

   In this case you can find the object by looking up any of the attributes of the object.

   `@schedules = Schedule.find_by_team_id(<attribute_id>)`

   **Result**: Returns an object if found. Returns nil if not found.

If you do not wish to throw an error or just want to check if the object for a particular attribute exists, use the dynamic finder method.